# MAC address conflict

Tags: mac

Computer A have two network ports, A1 and A2. Computer B have 1 port B1.

The MAC address of B1 and A2 are identical, but both computer connects to the same network using A1 and B1. A2 are not connected to anywhere, will it cause a problem on MAC conflict?

Comment: What we really want to know is, how did you get two NICs with the same MAC address?

Comment: Are these virtual servers? Those have the ability to set the MAC addresses...

Comment: Having more than one NIC with the same address is the starting point of network spoofing (ARP Poisoning)... http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arp-spoofing

Answer (score 4):

No, as long as the duplicate MACs are not in the same network, there will not be a problem.  But in the situation you describe, there might be a problem in the future.

What if network connections change in the future, and ports B1 and A2 end up on the same network?  That will cause problems.

You need to find out how you got 2 NICs with the same MAC, and change one of them if possible.